# How can i Activate Multiple check boxes from mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have saved multiple courses id's in course field for student in Mysql database..

Ex : course : 1,5,7,9

if i edit the student how can i activate selected courses..?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XEfs.png)

```
<?php
$courses_query=mysql_query("select * from `course` where status='1'");
while($c_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($courses_query)){
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="<?php echo $c_fetch['id']; ?>" id="courseid" <?php if($re['course']==$c_fetch['id']){ echo "checked='checked'"; } ?> /> <?php echo $c_fetch['course'];
?>
<?php
$cids=$c_fetch['id'];

$softw_qry=mysql_query("select * from `softwares` where course='$cids' and status='1'");
while($softw_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($softw_qry)){
?>

<input type="checkbox" name="software[]" value="<?php echo $softw_fetch['id']; ?>" <?php if($re['software']==$softw_fetch['id']){ echo "checked='checked'"; } ?> /> <?php echo $softw_fetch['software']; ?>

<?php
$soft_ids=$softw_fetch['id'];
$topicsn_qry=mysql_query("select * from `topics` where course='$cids' and software='$soft_ids' and status='1'");
while($topicn_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($topicsn_qry)){
?> 
<input type="checkbox" name="topics[]" value="<?php echo $topicn_fetch['id']; ?>" /> <?php echo $topicn_fetch['topic']; ?>
<?php } }} ?>
```

Comment: please post code example

Comment: We cannot help if you do not show the php code you are currently using. Or maybe even the javascript part, since you tagged this question with `ajax`.

Comment: <h6>
<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="<?php echo $c_fetch['id']; ?>" id="courseid" <?php if($re['course']==$c_fetch['id']){ echo "checked='checked'"; } ?> />           
<?php echo $c_fetch['course']; ?>
</h6>
<input type="checkbox" name="software[]" value="<?php echo $softw_fetch['id']; ?>" <?php if($re['software']==$softw_fetch['id']){ echo "checked='checked'"; } ?> >

Comment: but in database course field Multiple ids like 1,2,3,4.... If i student have single course its working and if they have multiple courses its not working

Comment: @shiva - provide your code in your post. Edit your post and put the code you have in there.